# is it possible to change an object instance from outside the class it was initialized in?

Tags: java, swing, class, instance

I may be going about this thing the wrong way. Please enlighten me. Thanks ahead of time!!!

```
void initialize() {
more code...
JEditorPane textPane = new JEditorPane();
textPane.setEditable(false);
textPane.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
textPane.setText(" THE MESSAGE I WANT TO CHANGE FROM OUTSIDE initialize()");
more code....

public static void SomePrintClass(){
JEditorPane textPane = new JEditorPane();
textPane.setText("SOME NEW TEXT );        // I am aware this doesn't work 
//but is there a way it can be made to work???
more code.....
```

Comment: Without more code it may be difficult to guide you, but could you not pass the instance of textPane into the constructor of SomePrintClass so it is holding the reference that it needs?

Comment: @Michael That sounds sensible, could you give me an example of how you would have done it?

Comment: Do you want to make changes to the JEditorPane from any other class?

Comment: @CodeRunner That may make my life easier. I am trying everything possible to find the best possible fit for the program I am constructing.

Comment: You can do every thing to the JEditoPane with my example. I edited the answer. Changed the font color of the JEditorPane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guessed that you want to change simply the text of JEditorPane from any other class.
If so then it is simple. `Make the JEditorPane static` and call its setText() method with the name of the class. For Example.

**First Class**.

```
public class First extends JFrame {

    static JEditorPane ep;
    First() {
        ep = new JEditorPane();
        setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        ep.setText("I expect to receive some text.");
        add(ep);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
    }
}
```

**Second Class.**

```
public class Second extends JFrame {

    JButton btn;
    JTextField jtf = new JTextField(16);
    JEditorPane ep;

    Second() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        btn = new JButton("Send above Text.");
        setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               ep = First.ep;
               ep.setText(jtf.getText());
               ep.setForeground(Color.red);
            }

        });
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(jtf);
        add(btn);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            First so;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Second();
                so = new First();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro this is what I ended up implementing and it worked how I had originally envisioned it! Props to you for being a mind reader!

Comment: My Pleasure. Brother thanks a lot. We are here to help you. Be happy.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example, basically you pass the instance of one class into the other via the constructor.  It could be done other ways as well...

```
public class StackOverflow_33061019 {

    public class ExampleClass
    {
        String displayText;

        public ExampleClass()
        {
        }

        public String getDisplayText()
        {
            return displayText;
        }

        public void setDisplayText(String text)
        {
            this.displayText = text;
        }
    }

    public class AnotherClass
    {
        ExampleClass updateMe;

        public AnotherClass(ExampleClass example)
        {
            updateMe = example;
        }

        public void changeText()
        {
            updateMe.setDisplayText("Updated text from AnotherClass");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        StackOverflow_33061019 ap=new StackOverflow_33061019();
        ap.runIt();
    }

    public void runIt()
    {
        ExampleClass example = new ExampleClass();
        example.setDisplayText("Initial text");
        System.out.println("ExampleClass displayText: " + example.getDisplayText());

        AnotherClass another = new AnotherClass(example);
        another.changeText();
        System.out.println("ExampleClass displayText: " + example.getDisplayText());
    }

}
```

Comment: This would probably work but I would have to go back and rethink where I was going with my original train of thought. Thank you for this example.

Comment: They don't have to be inner classes, and there are also other ways to do it.  This is just an example of passing the instance by reference and holding it.  You could share access to the object in other ways, or you could go as far as making an event bus/listener to update based on events.  Not knowing more about what you are working on, these are just generic suggestions